# Keep trailing zero's in excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need the following to show trailing zeros...

> $1.85 Daily, $7.4 Weekly, $22.2 Monthly

**$7.4** needs to show **$7.40**

**$22.2** needs to show **$22.20**

That needs to happen with every number. Here is the basic but long forumla we have setup for this.

> ="$"&B50&" Daily, "&"$"&E50&" Weekly, "&"$"&I50&" Monthly"

Just to quickly explain, we use this to compile the data into one cell that we can copy and paste from once cell to an email.

Comment: I use the ROUND function to help this and then show results to two decimal places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TEXT(B50,"$#,##0.00"" Daily, """) & TEXT(E50,"$#,##0.00"" Weekly, """) & TEXT(I50,"$#,##0.00"" Monthly""")
```

Answer (score 2):

To format values *for display* (without actual change to the value) you can use e.g:

`="The value is: " & TEXT(A1,"0.00") & " millimeters."`

Where `"0.00"` follows the same rules as "Format Cell" (CTRL+1)